# I Get "Vote too old to be changed" message but I have not voted on it

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Vote too old to be changed”… but I haven’t voted!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18360/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-but-i-havent-voted)

I can't vote on this question I get the "Vote to old to be changed" message even though I never voted on it. Clicking on the score shows no up- or down-votes at all.

[Screen capture in Mac is all black](https://superuser.com/questions/103310/screen-capture-in-mac-is-all-black)

**Edit:**
I think I understand what happened. I first saw the question and upvoted it, I then realised the owner of the question was not a member of SU (migrated from SO) and removed my vote. (I usually don't bother with questions with no owner). Later I came back and found that the user had registered and wanted to place my vote and encounter the error message.

Comment: The system begs to differ: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18360/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-but-i-havent-voted

Comment: If you voted and immediately rescinded the vote it won't show up on the question, but it will count as a vote and start the clock.

Comment: Again with the usability issues Atwood refuses to fix because he'd have to admit he's wrong about something...

Comment: @random - the system does not beg, it conquers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you vote, then revert the vote, you'll still get this message.
Don't ask me why.

Comment: it's because undoing votes is the #1 cause of reputation exploits in the system.

Comment: @Jeff: But once the vote has been undone why can't it be re-done?

Comment: The ultra-short window for reversing votes should have minimized this exploit to a minimum now. It's now virtually impossible to strategically downvote with any success.